# What exact changes are made on the installing computer while installing an Office-add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to ensure my Office-add-in is running properly in various environments. This includes complex environments like terminal server and Citrix solutions or systems with heavily limited user rights.

From former add-ins based on COM and VBA I know that of course the more changes are made on a users system (program folders, system folders, user profile, registry etc.) the more problems can occur in such environments.

Therefore I need to know the **exact changes made while installing an Office-add-in on the client machine**, using the following ways to deploy.

- Centralized Deployment, with and without referencing app source
- Manually installing from Office Store
- Network share

Since the Office-Add-In runs within a browser loaded from a network source no actual installation is needed. But at least the activation of the add-in, which makes office loading it, has to be saved somewhere. This probably includes the manifest file itself stored somewhere permanently or at least a reference to it.

For the network share installation I already know

- You need a network share and access to it in the users context
- Registry changes for the trusted catalog `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\office\16.0\WEF\TrustedCatalogs\...]`

And of cause it would be nice to know the changes for all the supported platforms (Windows, MAC & Online)

Comment: So it seems at least the folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\ is used as cache, but not as indicator for installed add-ins at least not from the Store installed ones

Comment: This is a very badly asked question - can you please clarify what do you mean by exact changes made? Made where? What type of changes are we referring to? On the installing computer? On the Office client? For Outlook addins or Word, Excel and PowerPoint?

Comment: The only thing that is installed on the user's computer is a reference to the manifest. The icons that the manifest points to are cached in the WEF folder.

Comment: @MaviDomates Thx for your response, it's about the installing computer. Sry if that wasn't clear enough, I edited the question. I didn't specify the kind of change because that's exactly I would like to know and I didn't specifiy the kind of Office application either, because I expect it to be the same for all kinds and if it isn't I would like to know.

Comment: @RickKirkham thx, can you tell me where exactly this reference is stored?

Comment: @Developer Actually, it looks like there are copies of the manifests in subfolders of `...\WEF\ -some-GUID-here- \ -some-hash-or-"OMEX"-here- \Manifests\`.

Comment: If I search \WEF for the GUID of an add-in, it appears in a couple of other files too. Also, if I search the Windows Registry for that GUID it appears in one place.

Comment: @RickKirkham It seems you also have to try and search manually, so thanks for you effort. I hoped you or somebody else would have access to some documentation about that...
I deleted WEF folder and registry key, and then the add-ins weren't there any more, but under Insert->Office-Add-Ins they still were shown and after pressing refresh on this window there were installed again. So there has to be another location where the installation is stored. Follow up question would be: is this stored differently for users with and without 365 subscription (in case of server side storage)

Comment: I think this might be a bug. Please raise this as an issue on the repo: [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I did https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/852

Comment: Does anybody know about the changes made on MAC?

Answer (score 1):

On installation of Office-Add-Ins on a Windows system the following changes are made

- File system `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF`
- Registry `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\office\16.0\WEF]`

The file system is used to cache the add-ins (manifest files, icons, java script etc.) and the registry is used to manage this data.

If you are signed in on Office, your add-ins also are stored for your identity and that's why they can and will be installed again (under certain circumstances) after above mentioned data gets lost